# Closure parameters out of scope of overriden generic function

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say we have a generic class A with a function that has a closure taking a a generic parameter.

```
class A<T>{
   func someTask(closure:(T) -> Void){

   }
}
```

Now I have a class B that inherits from class A invoking it with an Int.

```
class B:A<Int>{
    override func someTask(closure: (Int) -> Void) {
       closure(3)
    }
}
```

Why is the parameter of the closure in this function call out of bounds when the closure is executed?

```
b.someTask(){
   number in
   print(number)
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug to me – you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org). Also attempting to use `String` as `closure`'s parameter type will seemingly always result in the `closure` getting called with an empty string, no matter what is passed in.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'll do that.

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2984 filed bug report